# Saving more checkpoints Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am using the tensorflow object detection API on Cloud ML Engine to train a model. What I would like to know is, is there a way to save more model checkpoints in the `train` folder?
Right now the model saved the five latest checkpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `keep_checkpoint_max` to train_config in the config file. The default value is 5.

Answer (score 2):

The [`RunConfig`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) object accepts a parameter `keep_checkpoint_max` which defaults to 5. In `model_main.py` you can see a `RunConfig` object being instantiated ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/bc0edaf8ec635c2a493a9303071e3d2fe97f3b7b/research/object_detection/model_main.py#L50)):

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)
```

You would need to update that file to look like:

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, keep_checkpoint_max=5)
```

Or, equivalent, create a new flag that gets passed through.